# Adding a missing Month value with target and cumulative total values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given of the following main table query, I am trying to get to populate the missing months with the corresponding row number followed by target values and cumulative values.

It would be great to avoid using the CTE table as this query will be joined with both an attribute table query later that contains the target value by join and match the attribute table's row number with the current table row number. The other query is is a string split query - E.g `select cast(value as int) from string_split()`.

For example, this outlet code 174 has transactions between June 2021 until end of last month, except for months 6 and 7.

The SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(MONTH,rpt_date)
, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,rpt_date)) as [row_no]
, CAST(SUM(total_sales_amt) OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,rpt_date)) AS DECIMAL(14,2))
FROM summary_receipt
WHERE outlet_id = 174
AND bus_id = 6
AND rpt_date between CAST('2021-06-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2022-05-31' AS DATE)
```

The current result set (without months 6 and 7) returns like

| Month | Row | Total Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1993747 |
| 2 | 2 | 3276223 |
| 3 | 3 | 3983060 |
| 4 | 4 | 4985001 |
| 5 | 5 | 5861237 |
| 8 | 6 | 5922536 |
| 9 | 7 | 6295357 |
| 10 | 8 | 7044932 |
| 11 | 9 | 7930095 |
| 12 | 10 | 9068760 |

while the intended result that I am looking at is:
**Note**: Cumulative value remains the same as there are no transactions during months 6 and 7.

| Month | Row | Total Sales (cumulative) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1993747 |
| 2 | 2 | 3276223 |
| 3 | 3 | 3983060 |
| 4 | 4 | 4985001 |
| 5 | 5 | 5861237 |
| 6 | 6 | 5861237 |
| 7 | 7 | 5861237 |
| 8 | 8 | 5922536 |
| 9 | 9 | 6295357 |
| 10 | 10 | 7044932 |
| 11 | 11 | 7930095 |
| 12 | 12 | 9068760 |

Comment: A CTE is going to be the easiest solution here, if I am honest.

Comment: embrace CTE, dont avoid.

Comment: That `DISTINCT` doesn't feel right; with a `SUM` like that I suspect you *shouldn't* be getting any duplicate rows.

Comment: I don't think you can add records to a result set from querying a single table without any joins. You can't create what isn't there without a join. If a CTE must be avoided then I would suggest making this into a temp table and then an INSERT statement to fill in the blanks. Are subqueries allowed?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned a CTE would be one method.

Here you can use a `VALUES` table construct for your 12 months and `LEFT JOIN` from that to get 1 row per month. Then you can use a windowed `COUNT` to put the  rows into groups, where the group number is only increased when there is a non-`NULL` and then get the first value in said group with `FIRST_VALUE`:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(1,1,1993747),
            (2,2,3276223),
            (3,3,3983060),
            (4,4,4985001),
            (5,5,5861237),
            (8,6,5922536),
            (9,7,6295357),
            (10,8,7044932),
            (11,9,7930095),
            (12,10,9068760))V(Month,Row,Sales);
GO

WITH Months AS(
    SELECT V.[Month],
           --YT.[Row],
           YT.Sales,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN YT.Sales IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY V.Month) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))V(Month)
         LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON V.[Month] = YT.[Month])
SELECT M.Month,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY M.Month) AS [Row],
       FIRST_VALUE(M.Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY M.Grp ORDER BY M.Month) AS Sales
FROM Months M;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

For a bit of "fun", in SQL server 2022 onwards, you could use `LAG` with an `IGNORE NULLS` clause instead of a windowed `COUNT` to get the last non-NULL value, which wouldn't require a CTE (as you aren't using an aggregate on an aggregate):

```sql
SELECT V.[Month],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V.Month) AS [Row],
       ISNULL(YT.Sales,LAG(YT.Sales) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY V.Month)) AS Sales
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))V(Month)
      LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON V.[Month] = YT.[Month];
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of overcomplicating this, I wanted to post an approach that I use quite often, because it is flexible to re-use if you wanted to apply this to new data and do something similar.

That is why I use CTE's, because I can break this down and re-use it on new problems.

I also wrote this to work on *all* `bus_id`'s and `outlet_id`'s, so if you want to, you can filter the final query.

I also wrote this to handle datespines of more than just months, because sometimes people want to do this for datasets at weekly or hourly intervals as well.

My apologies in advance, that I used [Rasgo](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql)+[Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/) to build this SQL, so I'm taking advantage of their GENERATOR function in step 1 - which I know won't work in sql-server. Luckily the Datespine isn't too compicated, and you can probably recreate it my description.

The general approach is this:

1. **Datespine** - essentially you (a) create distinct intervals (b) distinct groupby items, then cross joined to (c) unique combinations of both, and finally, (d) outer join that to your regular data (missing intervals are now present)
2. **Aggregate** - use the newly created interval and aggregate to your monthly amount
3. **Cumulative** - use a window function.

```
WITH CTE_DATESPINE AS (
  WITH GLOBAL_SPINE AS (
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY 
          NULL
      ) as INTERVAL_ID, 
      DATEADD(
        'month', 
        (INTERVAL_ID - 1), 
        '2021-01-01T00:00' :: timestamp_ntz
      ) as SPINE_START, 
      DATEADD(
        'month', INTERVAL_ID, '2021-01-01T00:00' :: timestamp_ntz
      ) as SPINE_END 
    FROM 
      TABLE (
        GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 12)
      )
  ), 
  GROUPS AS (
    SELECT 
      BUS_ID, 
      OUTLET_ID, 
      MIN(RPT_DATE) AS LOCAL_START, 
      MAX(RPT_DATE) AS LOCAL_END 
    FROM 
      summary_receipt 
    GROUP BY 
      BUS_ID, 
      OUTLET_ID
  ), 
  GROUP_SPINE AS (
    SELECT 
      BUS_ID, 
      OUTLET_ID, 
      SPINE_START AS GROUP_START, 
      SPINE_END AS GROUP_END 
    FROM 
      GROUPS G CROSS 
      JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT 
          SPINE_START, 
          SPINE_END 
        FROM 
          GLOBAL_SPINE S
      )
  ) 
  SELECT -- here is where the datespine is created
    G.BUS_ID AS GROUP_BY_BUS_ID, 
    G.OUTLET_ID AS GROUP_BY_OUTLET_ID, 
    GROUP_START, 
    GROUP_END, 
    T.* 
  FROM 
    GROUP_SPINE G 
    LEFT JOIN summary_receipt T ON RPT_DATE >= G.GROUP_START 
    AND RPT_DATE < G.GROUP_END 
    AND G.BUS_ID = T.BUS_ID 
    AND G.OUTLET_ID = T.OUTLET_ID
), 
CTE_AGGREGATE AS ( --here we aggregate sum of sales
    SELECT 
        GROUP_BY_BUS_ID, 
        GROUP_BY_OUTLET_ID, 
        GROUP_START, 
        SUM(TOTAL_SALES_AMT) as TOTAL_SALES_AMT_SUM
    FROM 
        CTE_DATESPINE 
    GROUP BY 
        GROUP_BY_BUS_ID, 
        GROUP_BY_OUTLET_ID, 
        GROUP_START 
),
CTE_CUMSUM AS ( --here we run our cumulative sum
SELECT 
  *, 
  SUM(TOTAL_SALES_AMT_SUM) OVER(
    PARTITION BY GROUP_BY_BUS_ID, GROUP_BY_OUTLET_ID 
    ORDER BY 
      GROUP_START ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      AND CURRENT ROW
  ) as SUM_TOTAL_SALES_AMT_SUM 
FROM 
  CTE_AGGREGATE
) 
SELECT GROUP_BY_BUS_ID AS bus_id,
GROUP_BY_OUTLET_ID AS outlet_id,
GROUP_START AS rpt_date,
SUM_TOTAL_SALES_AMT_SUM AS total_sales_cumulative,
FROM CTE_CUMSUM
```